# In this JavaScript code, why can some functions access internal variables and others not?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var dp = dp || {
    VERSION : '0.00.02',
    startApp : function() {
        $(app.init);
        $(app.start);
    }
};
dp.startApp();
```

which calls app.init and app.start below:

```
var app = app || {};

app.init = function() {
    this.baseElement = $('div#app');
    $('body').css('background-color', 'beige');
};

app.start = function() {
    //this.baseElement.html('showing this'); //this works
    //this.show(); //error: show is not a function
    app.show(); //error: show is a function, but baseElement is undefined
};

app.show = function() {
    this.baseElement.html('showing this');
};
```

why in `app.start` does:

- the first line work
- the second line show it is not a function
- the third line say that baseelement is undefined

Comment: I assumed in my answer that `$` is a function (probably jquery). Can you confirm by adding the jquery tag if it's jquery ?

Comment: @dystroy if it quacks like jQuery it's jQuery (I'm counting 3 jQuery signatures there) :P

Comment: My answer is valable if its not jquery but another function :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are passing the functions to `document.ready`, jQuery will call them with `this` set to `document`. That means you can set arbitrary properties on `document` of course, but it's not a jQuery object so it doesn't have the methods you are calling.

You can try this:

```
$(dp.startApp) //Since `this` doesn't matter here
```

and

```
startApp : function() {
    app.init(); //Calling the functions as property of `app`, will make `this` set to `app`
    app.start();
}
```

I guess the biggest thing you are missing here is that the binding of `this` is dynamic and is determined by the way you call functions, not how you define them.

Answer (score 1):

`$(app.init);` calls the `app.init` function but the receiver isn't the `app` object.

So the `baseElement` variable isn't set in `init` in the correct object (`app`).

You may try `$(function(){app.init();app.start();});`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would structure your code:

```
$(function() {

    app = {
        init: function() {
            this.version = '0.00.02';
            this.baseElement = $("div#app");
            this.bindEvents();
            this.start();
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            $('body').css('background-color', 'beige');
        },
        start: function() {
            this.show();
        },
        show: function() {
            this.baseElement.html('showing this');
        }
    }

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    app.init();
});
```

Edit: I know this doesn't answer your question but it cleans it up a bit and makes it a bit easier to understand what's going on..